# About font and designs

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontspec, shapes

I'm new to Latex, I finally decided to learn it after having discovered that LibreOffice writer sucks. I thought it helps you create better text but after having spent almost two hours on this site, I saw questions about drawing shapes, creating book covers and fonts. So I thought I should ask you about it.

I don't have Latex on my PC, I use writelatex.com. Anyway:

- Is it possible to draw tears shape?
- Is it possible to write in bloody fonts such as [this one](http://www.fontspace.com/cloutierfontes/cf-my-bloody-valentine)?
- Is it possible to draw a flower or a rose? something [close to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzah9.jpg)? only the shape not the details

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't have an example now, I think I should delete it and reopen it when I have one

Comment: @HenriMenke oh no I didn't ask you to do it for me, I just ask is it feasible and if so where should I start looking, I am not asking you to write a single line of code! - I cannot write an example, I don't know if it's feasible in the first place

Comment: By the way, I can't view the image you linked to as I do not have permission.

Comment: @cfr which one? I'll edit the question tomorrow, both lonks are working fine from my phone, im not logged in anywhere so it doesn't require logging in

Comment: The flower. That's the only image you linked to as far as I can tell. (The other is a font.)

Comment: @cfr I changed the url of the flower. I uploaded it to imgur

Comment: Googling I've found [how-to-use-minion-pro-fonts-with-xelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/examples/how-to-use-minion-pro-fonts-with-xelatex/ydsdkcpvsstg#.U1jRY3Q4LME). I imagine that using bloody fonts has similar solution, add otf font files to your project folder in writelatex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concerning the fonts, it's easy to use any font known to the system if you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

For the other questions, LaTeX is *not* a drawing program. Some LaTeX packages or companion programs have graphic capabilities, some very impressive like `metapost`, `asymptote`, `TikZ/pgf` or `pstricks`,  but rather in the scientific domain. They all have a programming language and you must write a program in that language.

I don't know well `metapost`, but you can find information and links how it works on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaPost) about it. On [this site](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) you will find a lot of examples of what can be done with `TikZ`. Numerous examples of what can be done with `pstricks` can be found on the [PSTricks home page](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples). Many Asymptote examples are [here](http://www.piprime.fr/asymptote/).

You also can use a drawing sofware and include your drawings with the `graphicx` package, simply writing in your document:

\includegraphics{my_image}

The extension of a graphic file has to be `.ps` or `.eps` if you compile with LaTeX; `pdf`, `jpg` or  `png` with pdfLaTeX. If pdfLaTeX is launched with the `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeXLive), `.eps` or `.ps image files will be converted on the fly to the .pdf format by`epstopdf` and included in the resulting .pdf.

Many, many thanks to cfr for helping me to improve this answer.

Comment: Does writelatex.com really use your system fonts? I thought all the compilation must be done server-side? Note that I've never used it so I'm not disagreeing with you - I'm just surprised is all. Also, [basic metapost examples](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/Metapost/metapost.html) is useful. [Definitely not a showcase or example of 'what can be done' but more a demonstration of fundamental techniques.]

Comment: @cfr: I was giving a *general*  answer. I don't know writelatex.com, but I doubt they use *your* fonts. You're right, I forgot to mention Metapost (I never used it and don't know it well, for my excuse…). Added some explanations and a link to the Wikipedia page, which seems to be in the spirit of what you meant in your comment.

Comment: XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX of course.

Comment: @Christian/ Yes, of course. I add that at once.

Comment: Metapost is not a LaTeX package although you can use it with LaTeX and there are packages both to facilitate this and to use LaTeX code in metapost figures. About the link. Yes, I just meant I thought it should be included. That link is the one I find really useful when trying to figure out what it can do and how it can be done. (i.e. when the documentation is too abstract or confusing or I don't know what to look up!)

Comment: Of course, I know that. Just (mis)wrote a little too hastily. Asymptote isn't either. I'll change the wording.

Comment: pdfLaTeX can use postscript images if the conversion package is loaded.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for pointing this. Actually I've used this possibility only for pstricks figures up to now.

Comment: +1 I've never used it for pstricks (or, indeed, used pstricks) but I have tested it with `.eps` although most of the stuff I use is in `.png` or `jpg` format already. (Except occasional metapost figures. But metapost can output `.png` so...)